# video is playing fullscreen mode in android

Tags: android, android-webview, mediacontroller

i wish to play the webview video on full screen mode ...

if my video is start to play means its display and playing with fullscreen mode ..How can i develop these ??? give me any idea ???

if i have to click play button means the video is playing fullscreen mode.

I have used below code:

```
content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
final Activity activity = this;
content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
public void onProgressChanged ( WebView view , int progress ){
    activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
}       
 });

content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
public void onReceivedError ( WebView view , int errorCode , String description , String failingUrl ){
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

 });

content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

 content.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, full_content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);

    content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()
     {
        public void onProgressChanged ( WebView view , int progress )
        {

            activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }

            public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation,   WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback){
            super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);   
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=14) {
                if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {                  
                    content.addView(view, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER));                   
                    content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
            }
        } 


            });
```

pls give me any suggestion for playing video on full screen ???

In these code video is displayed particular width and height ly...how can i play the full screen mode ???

Answer (score 0):

I did it via youtube player API...these is easy one for android developer.it is played well on fullscreen mode.